# How to use VBA .Formula with row number incrementation?

Tags: vba

I am writing a macro which requires me to insert a formula to a number of consecutive cells in a column.

For row number 10, I must insert

```
=IF(D10="","",IFERROR(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,D10,A:A,A10,B:B,B10),"E"))
```

For row number 11, I must insert

```
=IF(D11="","",IFERROR(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,D11,A:A,A11,B:B,B11),"E"))
```

And so on...
However, the following hardcoded version (I did it just for trial) returns the 'Expected end of statement' error.

```
Cells(11, "F").Formula = "=IF(D11="","",IFERROR(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,D11,A:A,A11,B:B,B11),"E"))"
```

Is there any way to avoid this error and insert the formula by using rowNum variable?
I want to increment the row number (rowNum = rowNum + 1) after inserting the formula.
Also, if possible, I would like to use constant ERROR instead of hardcoding "E" in the formula.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to double up the quotes in the formula, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: You can write a formula with relative references to an entire range, and Excel will update the reference for each row, e.g. `Range("F10:F100").Formula = "=IF(D10="""","""",IFERROR(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,D10,A:A,A10,B:B,B10),""E""))`.

Comment: Hi Big Ben, Thanks a lot for helping me out! My macro works totally fine now...